# Automated SSL certificate check as a service?

Tags: saas, ssl

I have several sites that use Lets Encrypt SSL certificate and are set to auto renew at different dates.

Is there a service like pingdom.com or uptimerobot.com that would allow me to check if my sites Lets Encrypt SSL certificate has auto renewed correctly ?

Ive seen some scripts that can be installed on a web server to do this, but wondered if there was a SAAS solution with a GUI ?